# Delphi - extract string between tags (duplicate tags)

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to write a function to extract a string between two tags.
The problem is that the first tag is a duplicate in that string with an unknown count e.g.

```
Str := 'Delphi App Hello Hello SomeText here Hello Hello Hello This is a Test!';
```

What i want exactly is extract ***Hello This is a Test!***

- TagF is the last *Hello* word
- TagL is Test!

The duplicate count of TagF its random.

```
Function sExtractBetweenTagsB(Const s, LastTag, FirstTag: string): string;
var
  i, f : integer;
  sTemp : string;
begin
  sTemp := s;
  repeat
    Delete(sTemp,Pos(FirstTag, sTemp),length(FirstTag));
  until AnsiPos(FirstTag,sTemp) = 0;
  f := Pos(LastTag, sTemp);
  Result:= FirstTag+' '+Copy(sTemp, 1, length(sTemp));
end;
```

The output is:

```
Hello Delphi App   SomeText here    This is a Test!
```

Comment: Try `LastDelimiter` function

Comment: @Mbo: While convenient, I'd rather stay with `PosEx` on 32bit as it has a Fastcode optimization while `LastDelimiter` has not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function sExtractBetweenTagsB(Const s, LastTag, FirstTag: string): string;
var
  pLast,pFirst,pNextFirst : Integer;
begin
  pFirst := Pos(FirstTag,s);
  pLast := Pos(LastTag,s);
  while (pLast > 0) and (pFirst > 0) do begin
    if (pFirst > pLast) then // Find next LastTag
      pLast := PosEx(LastTag,s,pLast+Length(LastTag))
    else
    begin
      pNextFirst := PosEx(FirstTag,s,pFirst+Length(FirstTag));
      if (pNextFirst = 0) or (pNextFirst > pLast) then begin
        Result := Copy(s,pFirst,pLast-pFirst+Length(LastTag));
        Exit;
      end
      else
        pFirst := pNextFirst;
    end;
  end;
  Result := '';
end;

var
  s: String;

begin
  s := 'Delphi App Hello Hello SomeText here Hello Hello Hello This is a Test! Hello';
  WriteLn(sExtractBetweenTagsB(s,'Test','Hello'));
end.
```

Output:

```
Hello This is a Test
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`PosEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.PosEx) function to scan your string for the tag and seek forward:

```
program SO30827180;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  StrUtils;

function ExtractString(const Input : String; const TagF: String; const TagL : String) : String;

var
  LastPos : Integer;
  NewPos  : Integer;

begin
 Result := '';
 NewPos := Pos(TagF, Input);
 if NewPos <> 0 then
  begin
   LastPos := NewPos;
   // scan to last start tag
   while true do
    begin
     NewPos := PosEx(TagF, Input, NewPos+1);
     if NewPos <> 0 then
      LastPos := NewPos
     else
      Break;
    end;
   // now seek end tag, starting from last starting tag position
   NewPos := PosEx(TagL, Input, LastPos+1);
   if NewPos <> 0 then
    Result := Copy(Input, LastPos, NewPos-LastPos+Length(TagL));
  end;
end;

var
  Line : String;

begin
 Line := 'Delphi App Hello Hello SomeText here Hello Hello Hello This is a Test!';
 Writeln(Format('Input: "%s"', [Line]));
 Writeln(Format('Ouput: "%s"', [ExtractString(Line, 'Hello', 'Test!')]));
 Line := ' Test! Delphi App Hello Hello SomeText here Hello Hello Hello This is a Test! Some end chars';
 Writeln(Format('Input: "%s"', [Line]));
 Writeln(Format('Ouput: "%s"', [ExtractString(Line, 'Hello', 'Test!')]));
 Readln;
end.
```

Output from example:

```
Input: "Delphi App Hello Hello SomeText here Hello Hello Hello This is a Test!"
Ouput: "Hello This is a Test!"
Input: " Test! Delphi App Hello Hello SomeText here Hello Hello Hello This is a Test! Some end chars"
Ouput: "Hello This is a Test!"
```

Comment: Does not work if there is a first tag behind the last tag.

Comment: @LURD Well the requirements are not that clear, are they? If I understood the OP correctly, the extraction begins at the last starting tag. If there is no end tag after that, then the result should be empty, not?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with regex :

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  RegularExpressions;

var
  regEx : TRegEx;
  testString : string;
  m : TMatch;
begin
  testString := 'Delphi App Hello Hello SomeText here Hello Hello Hello This is a Test!';

  regEx := TRegEx.Create('(Hello(?!.*Hello).*?Test!)');
  m := regEx.Match(testString);

  if m.Success then
    WriteLn(m.Value)
  else
    WriteLn('No match.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Here the regular expression is

- **(Hello(?!.*Hello)**
  -- Match "Hello" with no instance of "Hello" later in the string (greedy lookahead)
- **.*?**
  -- lazy match anything
- **Test!)**
  -- match "Test!"

If you want to generalize :

```
function ExtractBetweenTags(const s : string; FirstTag, LastTag : string) : string;
var
  regEx : TRegEx;
begin
  regEx := TRegEx.Create(Format('(%s(?!.*%s).*?%s)', [FirstTag, FirstTag, LastTag]));
  result := regEx.Match(s).Value;
end;
```